# Why are my form field names arriving with square brackets when I post via jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am using jquery's POST api (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send some form data to my server. When the server parses the request one of the fields has square brackets added to the name, eg. `foo` becomes `foo[]`. This is breaking the form handling on the server. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send an array or a form where multiple inputs have the same name, jquery adds the square brackets.

It is totally valid to send duplicate params in url encoded data by simple repetition eg. `foo=bar&foo=baz&foo=qux`is a valid thing to send to a server. Most servers will parse this into a variable called `foo` that contains an array of the values.

In order to make jquery behave 'correctly' (ie. send the fields with their actual names), it is necessary to add a `{traditional: true}` option to the request.

eg:

```
let data = {foo: ['bar', 'baz', 'quz']};
$.post({url:'/myurl', data: data, traditional: true, success: onSuccess});
```

I will admit to being baffled by jquery's decision to silently rename fields - this is potentially going to waste a lot of time (as it did for me) trying to debug mysterious errors.